# Failed to read artifact descriptor for commons-jxpath:commons-jxpath:jar:1.3-osgi:

Tags: java, maven-3

I am facing below mentioned error while building through maven . I have tried many solutions like using mirror but none of them is working . Please point me in some direction to fix the issue.

```
Downloading: http://repository.codehaus.org/org/beanshell/bsh/2.0b4-osgi/bsh-2.0b4-osgi.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6.779 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-05-23T13:26:22+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/308M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project net-myproject-ticketing-reports: Could not resolve dependencies for project net.myproject.ticketing.reports:net-myproject-ticketing-reports:jar:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at com.myproject.resourcelib.thirdparty.framework:mule-mule-2.2.1:jar:2.2.1 -> org.mule.transports:mule-transport-bpm:jar:2.2.1 -> org.mule.modules:mule-module-client:jar:3.4.0 -> org.mule.modules:mule-module-xml:jar:3.4.0 -> commons-jxpath:commons-jxpath:jar:1.3-osgi: Failed to read artifact descriptor for commons-jxpath:commons-jxpath:jar:1.3-osgi: Could not transfer artifact commons-jxpath:commons-jxpath:pom:1.3-osgi from/to codehaus (http://repository.codehaus.org): Failed to transfer file: http://repository.codehaus.org/commons-jxpath/commons-jxpath/1.3-osgi/commons-jxpath-1.3-osgi.pom. Return code is: 503 , ReasonPhrase:Service Unavailable. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that codehaus.org was closed and is no longer available, but older versions of Mule still mention that repository as a place to resolve some dependencies. Specifically `commons-jxpath:commons-jxpath:jar:1.3-osgi` which appears to be non-standard rebundling of version 1.3 with added OSGI support.

What you can do:

1. use a newer version of Mule that [no longer depends](https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-6854) on custom artifacts that are not available in standard repositories
2. find a different repository that hosts this artifact and add custom repository location either to user settings.xml or project pom.xml.

With option 2 random googling presents this repository: (not sure if it's a good choice!)

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>mule-old-dependencies</id>
    <url>http://repository.idega.com/maven2</url>
    <snapshots>
      <enabled>false</enabled>
    </snapshots>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```